# How to enable pgsql in PHP-FPM from a bash script for phpPgAdmin

Tags: 14.04, php, postgresql, php7, phppgadmin

I'm new to Linux and I have run across a problem that I cannot seem to solve.

Running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Trusty

I'm working on a Vagrant file to spin up a new fresh dev environment as whenever we need one. I'm having a problem with phpPgAdmin: It gives me the following message whenever I hit it on the browser:

```
Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option.
```

I have tried several different configurations putting the --with-pgsql in places in my command (see below), but they all cause the server not to respond.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y git nginx-full php7.0 php7.0-fpm php-pgsql postgresql-client-9.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The module for php-pgsql changed from 'php-pgsql' for PHP5 and changed to 'php7.0-pgsql' for PHP7. Therefore my command should be

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y git nginx-full php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-pgsql postgresql-client-9.5